# proving that $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 1<|z-1|<2\}$ is polygonally connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

I have the following set :
$$ A=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 1 < |z-1| < 2\}.$$
It's obvious that any two points in A can be connected by at least two line segments .

Note
 :(I am also Considering the case that if 2 points can be connected by one segment I will divide that segment also to two )

So,  $$\forall z_{1},z_{2} \in \mathbb{C}$$
 It is enough to find z such that :
$$ |z-z_{1}|=|z-z_{2}| \ , [z_{1},z]\cup[z,z_{2}]\subseteq A
$$
Is there any other idea to prove that A is polygonally connected algebraically ?and if f is continuous and B connected then  f(B) is connected .

How Can I find such f and B ?such that f(B)=A

I found out that z must be  $$
z=x+i\frac{2xa-a^2-b^2+c^2+d^2}{2d-2c}$$
where $$z_{1}=(a,b) , z_{2}=(c,d) , x \in \mathbb{(-2,-1)\cup(2,3)}$$

Thank you .

Comment: And the maximum number of steps needed to go from $z_1$ to $z_2$ seems to be $\color{red}{\bf 3}$.

Comment: "It's obvious that any two points in A can be connected by at least two line segments" Rereading more carefully the rest of your post, I now see that you pretend that every pair of points M and N in A can be connected by a single point P in a way such that MP and PN are included in A. To see that this is wrong, consider M close to 0 and N close to 2, both on the real axis, then such a point P would correspond to an affix whose real part should be simultaneously roughly greater than 2 and smaller than 0, which is impossible. However, as already mentioned, two points P and Q are ...

Comment: ... enough to guarantee that MP, PQ and QN are all included in A.

Comment: So ,any two points can be connected by at least two segments and at the extreme case I need exactly three segments .

Comment: Some points can be connected by one segment only...

Comment: Thank you very much .you're right  I didn't notice the extreme case that you have mentioned ,but the points that can be connected by one segment I can consider that those points can be connected by two segments by dividing the segment to two .

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe a geometric process using words. Perhaps you should read this with pencil and paper drawing things as I describe.

Let A,B be the two points in the annulus. Draw a circle concentric to the boundary of the annuli and passing though B.

Now draw any line segment from A to this newly drawn circle intersecting it at B1. Now B and B1 are in the same circle.  Now a sequence of chords of sufficiently short length (so that it won't  intersect the inner boundary of the annulus) can take one from B1 to B; so the initial line segment from A to B1 followed by this sequence of  chords is a polygonal path lying completely inside the annulus.